# Summing values for a particular key in a list of dicts in python

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

This is a icky little problem that I am stuck with..I have a list of dicts which is as follows:

```
[{'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 4},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 3},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 1},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 6},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra SC',
  'total_prescriptions': 8},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra SC',
  'total_prescriptions': 1},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra SC',
  'total_prescriptions': 3}]
```

What I would want to do is to sum up the total prescriptions across the various dicts for each medication and append the final sum as an entry to each dict as follows:

```
[{'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 4,
  'final_count': 14},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 3,
  'final_count': 14},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 1,
  'final_count': 14},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 6,
  'final_count': 14},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra SC',
  'total_prescriptions': 8,
  'final_count': 12},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra SC',
  'total_prescriptions': 1,
  'final_count': 12},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra SC',
  'total_prescriptions': 3,
  'final_count': 12}
 ]
```

What is the most efficient way of accomplishing this ?

Comment: Why did you choose the other answer, which is the same as mine, except slower?

Comment: Oh, I see he edited it to correct its unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from collections import Counter

```
counts = Counter()
for dct in lst:
    counts[dct['medication_name']] += dct['total_prescriptions']
for dct in lst:
    dct['final_count'] = counts[dct['medication_name']]

from pprint import pprint    as pp
```

Output:

```
[{'final_count': 14,
  'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 4},
 {'final_count': 14,
  'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 3},
 {'final_count': 14,
  'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 1},
 {'final_count': 14,
  'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 6},
 {'final_count': 12,
  'medication_name': 'Actemra SC',
  'total_prescriptions': 8},
 {'final_count': 12,
  'medication_name': 'Actemra SC',
  'total_prescriptions': 1},
 {'final_count': 12,
  'medication_name': 'Actemra SC',
  'total_prescriptions': 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
tot = defaultdict(int)
for d in your_dict_list:
    tot[d['medication_name']] += d['total_prescriptions']

for d in your_dict_list:
    d['final_count'] = tot[d['medication_name']]
```

Something like that should be reasonably efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict


dlist = [{'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 4},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 3},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 1},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'total_prescriptions': 6},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra SC',
  'total_prescriptions': 8},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra SC',
  'total_prescriptions': 1},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra SC',
  'total_prescriptions': 3}]


indexes = defaultdict(list)

for i in xrange(0, len(dlist)):
    indexes[dlist[i]['medication_name']].append(i)

for med_k, med_list in indexes.iteritems():
    tot = sum([dlist[i]['total_prescriptions'] for i in med_list])
    for i in med_list:
        dlist[i]['final_count'] = tot
```

This is fairly efficient, as it only loops **once for each dict in list**, then **once for each different med name**.

Answer (score 0):

Using groupby and itemgetter:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
L = [ (i['medication_name'],i['total_prescriptions']) for i in dlist]
sum_dict = dict([(x, sum(map(itemgetter(1), y))) for x, y in groupby(L, itemgetter(0))])
for i, v in enumerate(dlist): dlist[i]['final_count'] = sum_dict[v['medication_name']]
print dlist
```

Output:

```
[{'medication_name': 'Actemra IV', 'final_count': 14, 'total_prescriptions': 4}, 
{'medication_name': 'Actemra IV', 'final_count': 14, 'total_prescriptions': 3}, 
{'medication_name': 'Actemra IV', 'final_count': 14, 'total_prescriptions': 1}, 
{'medication_name': 'Actemra IV', 'final_count': 14, 'total_prescriptions': 6}, 
{'medication_name': 'Actemra SC', 'final_count': 12, 'total_prescriptions': 8}, 
{'medication_name': 'Actemra SC', 'final_count': 12, 'total_prescriptions': 1}, 
{'medication_name': 'Actemra SC', 'final_count': 12, 'total_prescriptions': 3}]
```